# How to get the highest second value from an hash

Tags: ruby

I have an hash like the following.

```
myhash = {123=>["pizza", 9.99], 234=>["Bread", 132.0], 456=>["burgers", 5.24]}
```

I want to be able to somehow get it to only show the highest priced object which in this case is bread.

So the result would be same as

```
puts "234 Bread 132.0"
```

Comment: Suppose the three values were `9.99`, `132.0`, `132.0`. `9.99` is the "second highest value". Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
highest_priced_object = myhash.max_by { |id, (item, price)| price }
```

Comment: last or `value[1]`

Comment: or you can do `value[-1]`

Comment: Another variant: `myhash.max_by { |number, (name, price)| price }`

Comment: One more step: `highest_priced_object.flatten.join(' ') #=> 234 Bread 132.0"`.

Answer (score 1):

[Max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) accepts a block, in which you can define the value you'd like to use for comparison. In this case, the second (or last) element in the array.
Finally, [join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) concatenates everything into a String.

```
myhash.max_by { |_, values| values.last }.join(' ')
```